# Python pip firebase-admin issue

Tags: python, pip, firebase-admin

Yesterday I wanted to play with firebase messaging and python, but I encountered the following issue when trying to install the package: if I install the package (firebase-admin) through pip, the importation doesn't work in my project. I tried installing it through PyCharm (so in the virtual environment of my project) and it works perfectly. Does anyone know what I'm missing here? I checked and the package is correctly installed (version 5.1.0).

Also does anyone know is there is a difference between firebase-admin and firebase_admin? (I tried installing both)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Starting Backwards

- [firebase-admin](https://pypi.org/project/firebase-admin/) is the official name for the PyPi package for Firebase in Python.
- The [firebase_admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin) package however, is what Google and Firebase have named the folder internally, and is why you install the package as follows:

```sh
pip install firebase-admin
```

But once the package is on your machine, you import the individual modules from `firebase_admin` in your code as follows:

```py
from firebase_admin import firestore, initialize_app, <otherModule etc...>
```

As far as I've seen, there is no `firebase_admin` package on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=firebase_admin)- There may however be an alias to firebase-admin that I am unaware of, but do not take my word on this.

### As for the installation issues

One reason you may be encountering issues when using Pycharm is that Jetbrains /Pycharm may be creating a [Virtual Environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) for you without you knowing.

By running `pip install firebase-admin` in newly opened terminal, you install the package in your global python package index. If Pycharm is starting the Virtual Environment they've set up when you open the IDE, it likely won't have any knowledge of your global packages.

A good practice is to create your own Virtual Environment and activating it when you start working on the project.

You can create the officially supported [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) environment by running,

```sh
python3 -m venv ./path/to/your/project/venv
```

Alternatively you can navigate to the root of your project and run `python3 -m  venv venv/`.

Now you should be able to activate it by running,

```sh
source venv/bin/activate
```

If you created the venv in **Mac/Linux** environment or,

```sh
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

In **Windows**.

See the official docs [Here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment).

Lastly, if you are uploading this project to a VCS repository like GitHub, don't forget to add `venv/` to your `.gitignore` as the folder can be quite large.

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much sense and I had no idea about Pycharm having no knowledge of the global packages.